# Invoke method not working on a windows open dialog box

Tags: c#, windows, modal-dialog, ui-automation

I've trying to do some automation with Microsoft UI automation with C# and on the first step I tried to do some automation with notepad. What I've tried to achieve that to start notepad and open a txt file from a random place.

What I've already achieved:

- Open notepad
- Invoke(expand) the filemenu and Invoke(click) on the "Open..." button.
- Write the path of the filename into the File name textbox of the popup Open dialog box (strangely I'm not able to Invoke a click action onto the address bar, but to handle that, that is going to be the next task).

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace TestUIAutomation
{

    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process p = Process.Start(@"notepad.exe");
    SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    var baseSoftware = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new 
    PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Untitled - Notepad"));

    var fileButton = baseSoftware.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new 
    propertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "File"));

    var fileButtonExpand = Utilitiy.ExCoPattern(fileButton);

    if (fileButtonExpand.Current.ExpandCollapseState != ExpandCollapseState.Expanded)
            {
                fileButtonExpand.Expand();
            }

    var openButton = baseSoftware.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Open..."));
            Utilitiy.GetInvokePattern(openButton).Invoke();

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    var addressBar = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "File name:"));

    SendKeys.SendWait(@"C:\Users\user1\Documents\Test.txt");

    var findOpenButton = new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Open"), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "1"));


    var openButtonDialog = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, findOpenButton);

    Utilitiy.GetInvokePattern(openButtonDialog);
}
}
}
```

Utility cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Automation;

namespace TestUIAutomation
{
    class Utilitiy
    {
        public static void SetCombobValueByUIA(AutomationElement ctrl, string newValue)
        {
            ExpandCollapsePattern exPat = ctrl.GetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern) as ExpandCollapsePattern;

            if (exPat == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Bad Control type...");
            }

            exPat.Expand();

            AutomationElement itemToSelect = ctrl.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new
                                  PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, newValue));

            SelectionItemPattern sPat = itemToSelect.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as SelectionItemPattern;
            sPat.Select();            
        }
        public static InvokePattern GetInvokePattern(AutomationElement element)
        {
            return element.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
        }
        public static TogglePattern CheckBoxPattern(AutomationElement element)
        {
            return element.GetCurrentPattern(TogglePattern.Pattern) as TogglePattern;
        }
        public static SelectionItemPattern RadioButtonPattern(AutomationElement element)
        {
            return element.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as SelectionItemPattern;
        }
        public static ValuePattern TextValuePattern(AutomationElement element)
        {
            return element.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
        }
        public static ExpandCollapsePattern ExCoPattern(AutomationElement element)
        {
            return element.GetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern) as ExpandCollapsePattern;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem at the moment I won't receive any error message, so the program actually invoke the open button but in real life nothing happens.
I can use sendkeys method enter input to open the file but if it's possible I like to invoke the open button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution, I forgot to actual invoke the button.

I change the last line from this

```
Utilitiy.GetInvokePattern(openButtonDialog);
```

To this

```
Utilitiy.GetInvokePattern(openButtonDialog).Invoke();
```